# Return highest number value in column cell plus a related row cell data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, concatenation, worksheet-function

```
        |A      B          C       D
--------|---------------------------------
1       |YEAR   NAME    UNITS   SOLD    
2       |2011   Jon     99      55
3       |2012   Jon     70      22
4       |2013   Jon     65      34
5       |2014   Jon     78      44
```

I would like to know how to find the year `Jon` sold the most (in this case the `55` in D2).

I know `=MAX(D2:D5)` will get me the `55`, but I would like to display something like `55 (2011)` in one column or two if not possible in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MAX(D:D)&"("&INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(D:D),D:D,0))&")"
```

will only return one year even if the maximum value arises in more than one year.